# Is it possible to show a Boolean icon in the Django admin only if returned a boolean, else the actual return value?

Tags: django, django-admin

Yes, I know about `myfield.boolean = True`. What I am asking is, is it possible to do something like this:

```
def get_nominees(self, obj):
    return ", ".join([nominee.name for nominee in obj.nominees.all()]) \  # returns a string
        or False  # returns a False icon
```

When I attempt to do this with, e.g. `get_nominees.boolean = True`, I get a `KeyError`.

Comment: Where is your callable being called from? get_nominees.boolean does nothing.

Comment: @professorDante, `get_nominees.boolean = True` is just a flag to tell the admin to prettify the True/False values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible to do this with `myfield.boolean = True` - see [django's source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5.4/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py#L170)

This is probably the easiest way to achieve what you're trying to do:

```
def get_nominees(self, obj):
    from django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_list import _boolean_icon
    return ", ".join([nominee.name for nominee in obj.nominees.all()]) \
        or _boolean_icon(False)
get_nominees.allow_tags = True
```

Note that the method `_boolean_icon`, with its prepended underscore, is probably not meant to be used this way, and might change without notice in a future version of django.